# Geolocation hangs after x attemps, works after browser restart

Tags: javascript, html, browser, geolocation

I'm working on a script that needs to grab my geolocation. It works most of the time, However every now and then the geolocation is not aquired and I have to restart the browser for it to work again. This occurs in Safari and FF (Not tested in IE and Chrome). Does anybody know what could be causing this? I'm using this bit of code from the book "HTML 5".

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadDemo() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "HTML5 Geolocation is supported in your browser.";
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateLocation);
    }
}

function updateLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    if (!latitude || !longitude) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "HTML5 Geolocation is supported in your browser, but location is currently not available.";
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FF sometimes hangs, don't know about safari. It doesnt work in IE yet as far as i know. It seems to work great in Chrome so far.
You can "solve" this by setting a timeout. It still doesn't work but at least the script is terminated after a while. I use this code.
If you you found a good fix please let me know.

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            //succes handler
        },
        function errorCallback(error) {
            //error handler
        },
        {
            enableHighAccuracy:false,
            maximumAge:Infinity,
            timeout:5000
        }
    );
```

Comment: I was having this problem both in Chrome on PC and in the Android browser, and adding this snippet made the code stop hanging at all, even though I changed the timeout to 10000ms. I believe it has something to do with maxiumumAge. Unfortunately for me, my html5 app must accurately track a user's position, so I cannot set maximumAge to infinity. I tried this again with enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:0, timeout: 10000 and it is still happily churning along. I believe simply supplying values to these parameters somehow prevents it from locking up.